# PDO sqlsrv don't run execute query to the end

Tags: php, pdo

i'm trying to use PDO and while loop statement in sql server query to insert to database but the while loop not run to the end although it work fine with simple query, i only use XAMPP to run server.

here my script to insert all days from 2017-01-01 to 2018-01-01 (yyyy-MM-dd):

```
try{
    $dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=MyServer,1433;Database=MyDB;";   
    $db = new PDO($dsn, "sa", "MyPassword"); 
    $db->setAttribute (PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 60); 

    $query = "DELETE FROM TEST

              declare @TempDate as date
              declare @FDate as date = Cast('2017-01-01' as date)
              declare @TDate as date = Cast('2018-01-01' as date)
              declare @DayInMonthList as Table(AllDayDate varchar(8))

              BEGIN
                   SET @TempDate = @FDate
                   WHILE(@TempDate < @TDate)
                   BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO TEST(FromDate, ToDate, TempDate) VALUES(@FDate, @TDate, @TempDate)
                        SET @TempDate =DateAdd(day, 1, @TempDate) 
                   END
              END";

        $cmd = $this->db->prepare($query); 
        if(!$cmd->execute()){
            throw new PDOException ($cmd->errorInfo());
        } 
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

This script insert about 120 rows without any error, what is wrong with my code ? please help me!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Getting any error

Comment: @SuvethanNantha output should be 365 rows inserted into TEST table

Comment: @user3656162 ok give me few minutes

Comment: @itsme i didn't get any error

Comment: @pantan Check the answer provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
try{
    $dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=MyServer,1433;Database=MyDB;";   
    $db = new PDO($dsn, "sa", "MyPassword"); 
    $db->setAttribute (PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 200); 
    $db->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $query = "DELETE FROM TEST

              declare @TempDate as date
              declare @FDate as date = Cast('2017-01-01' as date)
              declare @TDate as date = Cast('2018-01-01' as date)
              declare @DayInMonthList as Table(AllDayDate varchar(8))

              BEGIN
                   SET @TempDate = @FDate
                   WHILE(@TempDate < @TDate)
                   BEGIN
                        SET NOCOUNT ON;
                        INSERT INTO TEST(FromDate, ToDate, TempDate) VALUES(@FDate, @TDate, @TempDate)
                        SET @TempDate =DateAdd(day, 1, @TempDate) 
                   END
              END";

        $cmd = $db->prepare($query); 
        if(!$cmd->execute()){
            throw new PDOException ($cmd->errorInfo());
        }
        $db->commit();
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Always do beginTransaction and commit while doing PDO execution as shown below.

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->commit();
```

Also you have to add the below code before the insert statement to stop break from loop while insertion.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

I hope this will help you. If you have any problems or doubts let me know.

Comment: @pantan can you upvote the answer as correct if its working fine.

Comment: i'm upvoted but it show "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @pantan that's ok brother